# Add / Remove reaction event no longer firing Discord.js v13

Tags: discord.js

Good morning everyone,
I am currently running into one pretty irritating issue with getting a users messages from before the bots launch. I have been able to do this in the past (a few months ago), but it seems they have replaced the Intents.FLAGS approach for GatewayIntentBits. This has not been to complicated to change, but some problems have occurred.

One of the biggest issues, and the reason for this question is that even though I contain data in my intents that would allow for reading of reactions, as well as adding partials (I read it may help online). This does not seem to fix the issue.

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers], partials:["Message", "Channel", "Reaction"]})

. . .

client.on('messageReactionAdd', _ => {
    console.log('a reaction has been added');
});

client.on('messageReactionRemove', _ => {
    console.log('a reaction has been removed');
});
```

I know this isn't allot to go off of, but I have tested it with barely anything in my application and I still run into this error. Is this a known issue with the change to GatewayIntentBits? I would love to continue working on this bot.

Thank you for any assistance you may be able to provide.

EDIT: I have managed to get the reactions to work on the application now. I have not even started touching those old messages, and its working. Thank you for your help. My best bet of why its working is that the messages needed to be resent with the partials and intents specified above. I dont know why this didnt work before, but whatever.

Comment: Just to make sure, are you using v13 or v14 of discord.js? Do `messageReactionAdd` and `messageReactionRemove` fire when you react to messages created after the bot is online?

Comment: yes, currently messages created after launching the program can be reacted to just fine. I am currently looking back at the documentation as well, and I was mistaken. I am on version 14.

Answer (score 0):

Your gateway intent bits are fine, you need to do something similar to that for the partials as well, you need to import partials from discord.js and use them like that.

```js
const { Client, Partials } = from 'discord.js';
const client = new Client({
    intents: [],
    partials: [Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction]
});
```

Comment: Well yes, this does work. The only issue is that this is being used to add roles to people by adding reactions to an old post. These events work if I make a new post, not use an old post. I also have already used all those intents in the above code; thanks anyways though.

Comment: @CurtisPritchard - edited post, should help you out.